# NoSuchFieldError while creating session factory in Hibernate OGM

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, odm

the error i'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ERRORS_IGNORED
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.options.WriteConcernType.<clinit>(WriteConcernType.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.options.impl.WriteConcernOption.<clinit>(WriteConcernOption.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.options.navigation.source.impl.ConfigurationOptionValueSource$ConfigurationBasedOptionContainer.getAll(ConfigurationOptionValueSource.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.options.navigation.impl.OptionsContextImpl.getMostSpecificContainer(OptionsContextImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.options.navigation.impl.OptionsContextImpl.getAndCacheOptionsContainer(OptionsContextImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.options.navigation.impl.OptionsContextImpl.getUnique(OptionsContextImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.configuration.impl.MongoDBConfiguration.<init>(MongoDBConfiguration.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider.configure(MongoDBDatastoreProvider.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectInitiator.initiateService(GridDialectInitiator.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.GridDialectInitiator.initiateService(GridDialectInitiator.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.OgmDialectFactoryInitiator$OgmDialectFactory.<init>(OgmDialectFactoryInitiator.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.OgmDialectFactoryInitiator.initiateService(OgmDialectFactoryInitiator.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.OgmDialectFactoryInitiator.initiateService(OgmDialectFactoryInitiator.java:25)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmJdbcServicesInitiator$OgmJdbcServicesImpl.configure(OgmJdbcServicesInitiator.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at db.DatabaseUtils.getInstance(DatabaseUtils.java:14)
    at app.BattleshipsApp.main(BattleshipsApp.java:30)
```

here is my start class part when i create and use session factory:

```
SessionFactory sf = DatabaseUtils.getInstance();
Session session = sf.openSession();

Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

session.save(player1);

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

and this is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.grid_dialect">org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.mongodb.MongoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class">jdbc</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.connection_timeout">5000</property>

        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider">mongodb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database">BattleshipsDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host">127.0.0.1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.port">27017</property>

        <!--<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">JBossTS</property>-->
        <mapping class="model.Player"></mapping>
        <mapping class="model.GamesHistory"></mapping>


    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

pom.xml part with mongo driver and odm versions:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <hibernateOgmVersion>4.2.0.Final</hibernateOgmVersion>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernateOgmVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernateOgmVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-infinispan</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernateOgmVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

I expect to create a session factory and return it from method.
I tried changing hibernate.cfg.xml but google lacks answer for that.

Comment: I am no expert in Hibernate nor MongoDB, but I would guess that you are using an old version of Hibernate. From looking at the source of the `WriteConcernType` class, a field looks to have been removed from a MongoDB class but you appear to be using an old version of Hibernate that still attempts to use this field. Please edit your question to include the versions of Hibernate and the MongoDB driver that you are using.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I added hibernate versions as you wish. Can't deny this no fresh one but it's part of an old code I adapted. That;s why I haven't changed pom.xml file.

Comment: Well Hibernate OGM 4.2.0 was released in June 2015, and `org.mongo:mongodb-driver` (note: not `mongodb-java-driver`, there's nothing on Maven Central for that) version 3.12.11 was released in April 2022. So you'll either have to upgrade Hibernate or downgrade the Mongo Java driver.